# python - Django Translation of class variables

Tags: django, python-3.x, email, django-models, activation

Under the ActivationKey class, I generate a random key with a key variable of 50 characters. I do this to confirm the e-mail. The point I attach is that when I create a servlet key that will be a key variable (such as verification / {key}) that has a url generator and a key that is somewhere in the variable and a variable (such as verification / {key}) then I will not create a link using this url (like verficaton / asasaassassassassassa) When I click on the URL in the structure I specify for the view will work, key control and verifiyicek. I need to write a view using RedirectView that will perform only one operation and will go somewhere else;
URLs
view
I do not know how to make models.py like the following.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name=_('Email'), max_length=255, unique=True
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('First Name'), 
        max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Last Name'), 
        max_length=50)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Active'), 
        default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Staff'), 
        default=False)
    is_verify = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Verify'), 
        default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('User')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Users')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_full_name()

    def get_full_name(self):
        return '{first_name} {last_name}'.format(
            first_name=self.first_name, last_name=self.last_name
        )

    def get_short_name(self):
        return '{first_name}'.format(first_name=self.first_name)


def activation_key():
    while True :
        key = (''.join(choice(hexdigits) for i in range(50)))
        if ActivationKey.objects.filter(key=key).count() == 0:
        return key

class ActivationKey(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(verbose_name=_('User'), to='users.User',
                         related_name='activatio_with_mail')
    is_used = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('Used'), 
             default=False)
    key = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Key'), max_length=50,
                       unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('ActivationKey')
        verbose_name_plural = _('ActivationKey')

    def __str__(self):
       return self.key

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if not self.pk:
            self.key = activation_key()
            super(ActivationKey, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It's not clear what is not working. Your description of the problem is too vague. Are you seeing an error? If so, which error and where?

Comment: No Error I need to approve user registration with redirectviews by linking key variable

Comment: Well if your url is /account/activate/<key> then why not create the URL pattern for that URL (in urls.py), with a view (in views.py) that looks up the key, checks if the key is valid and ends up redirecting the user to whatever page you want them to end up on?

Comment: My purpose is actually to link the key variable that I specify (in models.py) to send to the user who wants to register as a clickable link. If the user then clicks on this link and matches the key to it in the database with the link I sent to the user, complete the user registration. I do not know how to do this.

Comment: If you know the basics of Django, you should know how to create a URL pattern matching `/account/activate/<somekey>/`, a view with a `get(self, key)` method that checks the key and redirects the user and how to use `reverse` to create the URL to send to the user. If you don't know this, you should do yourself a favour and go through the Django tutorial, read the docs about [URL patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) and about  [generic `View`s](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/intro/#using-class-based-views).